# Relating limits of a mapping and limits of nets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ a net in $X$. Then $x_d$ converges to $x \in X$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists $d_0 \in D$ such that for all $d \geq d_0$ we have $x_d \in U$.
Denote the set of limits of $x_d$ by $\lim_{d \in D} x_d$ which can be empty, have one point or several different points. If $X$ is Hausdorff then $\lim_{d \in D} x_d$ has at most one point.

Let $\Omega \subseteq X$ be an arbitrary subset, $a \in X$ an accumulation point of $\Omega$ in $X$, $Y$ a further topological space and $f : \Omega \to Y$ an arbitrary map.
A point $y \in Y$ is called a limit of $f$ at $a$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $y$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f(\Omega \cap U \setminus \{ a \}) \subseteq V$.
Let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \subseteq Y$ denote the set of all limit points of $f$ at $a$ which can be empty, consisting of one point or of several points.

I was asking myself whether we can relate these two kinds of convergence. Consider the directed set $D := \{ \Omega \cap U \setminus \{ a \} \mid U \text{ nbhd. of } a \}$ with $d_1 \leq d_2 :\Leftrightarrow d_2 \supseteq d_1$ for $d_1, d_2 \in D$. Is it true that

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \bigcap \lim_{d \in D} f(x_d)$$

where the intersection goes over all nets $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ in $X \setminus \{ a \}$ with $a \in \lim_{d \in D} x_d$?

One inclusion can be easily established:
Let $y \in \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and fix a net $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ in $\Omega \setminus \{ a \}$ such that $a \in \lim_{d \in D} x_d$. In order to show that $y \in \lim_{d \in D} f(x_d)$ let $V$ be a neighborhood of $y$. For this $V$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f(\Omega \cap U \setminus \{ a \}) \subseteq V$ since $y \in \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$. For this $U$ there exists $d_0$ such that for all $d \geq d_0$ we have $x_d \in U$ since $x_d \to a$. Since $x_d \in \Omega \setminus \{ a \}$ it follows that $f(x_d) \in f(U \cap \Omega \setminus \{ a \}) \subseteq V$ and thus $y \in \lim_{d \in D} f(x_d)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the other inclusion, suppose $y \not\in \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$. Then there is a neighbourhood  $V \ni y$ such that for all neighbourhoods $U \ni a$, we have $f[\Omega \cap U-\{a\}] \not\subseteq V$. Now let $d \in D$, by the above we have $f[d] \not\subseteq V$, choose $x_d \in d$ with $f(x_d) \not\in V$. Then, by construction $a \in \lim_{d\in D} x_d$ as $x_d \in d$, but $y\not\in \lim_{d \in D} f(x_d)$, as $V \ni y$ does not contain any $f(x_d)$.

So $\bigcap \lim f(x_d) \subseteq \lim f(x)$

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks.